# What does one do to decrypt this?

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

'Encrypted': 10101110001011101000000001110111000101011100011101110000000011101110100010111000111010111011100

Context: This is simpler than you think. So simple the solution to this problem would be found on the last attempt where you go to the very basis of encryption/cyphering etc. Yet because it's so 'apparently simple' (I was told) even a person with a decryption mindset will take a while.

^ This is the only clue I got told and I feel stupid because of how 'apparently' simple it is yet I cannot figure out what to do. (Final decrypted message should be in text with a short sentence made by a friend - no reward, just satisfactory win which I already surrounded to).

Clue: Binary is just a cover-up, look for a pattern

I had no clue where else to submit this online and I came across this website hopefully correctly understanding that puzzles like these are potentially solved here?

P.S: I tagged 'cypher' as this was the closest genre I could think of for this problem. However, since I have no clue for the solution to the puzzle, it may or may not include cypher. Some sort of pattern in the binary?

Answer (score 13):

It looks to be a form of

> Morse Code

You can decode it by treating

> a 1 as a short, a 111 as a long, 000 as end of character, and 00000 as end of word.

Which when decoded comes out to be

> ur mum gay

I feel offended :)

Comment: Should you also have included an explanation for what "0" is? I think I can work it out from your answer but it would be better to be included!